# Error occurs when trying to put Angular app in React as a component

Tags: reactjs, angular

I need to put my Angular2+ app into the React project as a component(I am using TypeScript for both react and angular), i am trying to do that with the way explained in this website: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-dynamically-integrate-angular-in-react-and-share-data-between-both-c507e90b1f09

So, i created new web component in my AppComponent(in angular) and then i run

```
ng build
```

command to create the files i need to import in React.(main.js, polyfills.js, runtime.js, styles.css, styles.js (if it exists), and vendor.js)

After that, i put them in a directory in my react project and import them in my react component where i want to use my Angular app.
However, i got these errors when i compile the React app:

```
  Line 1:153:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:265:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:863:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:921:  Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 1:950:  Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 1:983:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

I got errors in runtime.js file which is created by Angular itself.
I tried to disable **no-unused-expression** by adding this lines in package.json(in React):

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": "off",
      "no-unused-expressions": "off"
    }
  },
```

But i still got the same errors.

Comment: So my haunch is that your use of eslint is causing the error, have you tried disabling the it in the files you used angular component? If that works, you can omit the troubling issues one by one.

Comment: @FarshadKazemi I tried `/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */` at the top of the component file which I import the files, but still got the same errors

Comment: I guess, in this stage, more data is needed to resolve the issue. Please put a sample code on codesandbox or a similar platform so that we can help you out.